# How to get rid of multiple language mixture on the command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, debian, language, locale

I installed a clean Debian 9 Stretch system from a 'netinst' CD. The default locale is set to `de_DE.UTF-8`. Some userland tool, namely `mkfs.ext4`, is giving me messages in mixed languages:

```
/dev/sdb7 hat ein ext4-Dateisystem mit Namen „tmp-rofs“
    auf Tue Jul 18 16:51:41 2017
 erzeugtProceed anyway? (y,N)
```

The confirmation is not recognized by 'y' but 'j' (German 'ja').

This is, btw., a strange German grammar - the preposition 'auf' is never used in conjunction with a date. The concatination 'erzeugtProceed' is strange as well.

As you can see, the base message is given in German language (as intended), except the date format and the final question.

I ran `dpkg-reconfigure locales` adding additionally the `en_US.UTF-8` locale (since I am going to write scripts using different locales) and setting the default locale to `de_DE.UTF-8` again, however, the behavior did not change.

What could be wrong in my configuration / How do I fix it? The aim is to get clean localized (German) messages.

---

EDIT: additional information

There are 2 locale related environment variables set:

```
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
GDM_LANG=de_DE.utf8
```

The content of `/etc/default/locale` is:

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
```

`locale -a` gives me:

```
C
C.UTF-8
de_DE.utf8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
```

The same behavior is present in both, the tty console and the GUI terminal.

---

Experimentally, I have tried to manually set some environment variables:

```
export LC_MESSAGES='de_DE.UTF-8'
export LC_RESPONSE='de_DE.UTF-8'
export LC_TIME='de_DE.UTF-8'
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb7 -L 'tmp-rofs'
```

But the same issue is still remaining.

Comment: I am not a native English speaker. Please feel free to edit the heading / text of my question to clarify my concern and fetch more people running into a similar issue by adding proper keywords.

Answer (score 1):

You can find useful information about this on [Debian wiki - Locale](https://wiki.debian.org/Locale)

**Manually**:

edit the file /etc/locale.gen and add your locale settings (one set per line), e.g.:

```
 de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8
 de_DE ISO-8859-1
 de_DE@euro ISO-8859-15
```

> The supported locales are listed in /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED.
>
> - Run the command locale-gen
> - Run the command locale -a to verify the list of available locales; note >that the spellings change.
> - If you've upgraded to Lenny and you have leftover LANG=... content in >/etc/environment, you should comment it out.
> - To use the new settings with your programs, log out and back in.

The following environment variables affect locale related behaviour of the system:

```
- LANG Determines the default locale in the absence of other locale related environment variables
- LANGUAGE
- LC_ADDRESS Convention used for formatting of street or postal addresses
- LC_ALL High precedence override for locale specific behaviour (overrides all other locale variables)
- LC_COLLATE Collation order
- LC_CTYPE Character classification and case conversion
- LC_MONETARY Monetary formatting
- LC_MEASUREMENT Default measurement system used within the region
- LC_MESSAGES Format of interactive words and responses
- LC_NUMERIC Numeric formatting
- LC_PAPER Default paper size for region
- LC_RESPONSE Determines how responses (such as Yes and No) appear in the local language
- LC_TELEPHONE Conventions used for representation of telephone numbers
- LC_TIME Date and time formats
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply so far. It does not solve my issue yet. I'll try to play around with your recent edit (env vars). Do you have an idea, if those **must** be set / why they did not get set in my installation?

Comment: See my answer below. You might find a bug fix.

Answer (score 0):

After turning the internet upside down, I found that there acually seems to be a bug in the `e2fsprogs` package.

see https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=856586

*I will not accept my own anser for some time yet to give people a chance to suppose some bug fix. The first (or cleanest) solution solving my issue will be accepted.*